# Is there a difference between Get-Item ending with a trailing wildcard and Get-ChildItem without a trailing wildcard

Tags: powershell

As an example, compare the following commands in Powershell:

```
Get-Item -Path "C:\Users\test.user\Desktop\*"
```

and

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\test.user\Desktop"
```

My limited testing indicates that there is no difference in the output.

If there is indeed no difference, this begs the question: Why does `Get-ChildItem` exist?

Comment: Try to *recurse* with `Get-Item`. (; Although it can be done, it would take extra logic but, same could be said about other cmdlets. Hell, even about *operators* as well such as: `-ieq`, `-icontains`, etc.. So what's the point since PowerShell is already case-insensitive? Pretty simple actually, it's to show the author's intent.

Comment: That is my suspicion, also. If it is indeed merely an approach to verbosely indicate intent to code reviewers/contributors, then the Powershell team has simultaneously increased simplicity (`Get-ChildItem` is more descriptive) and complexity (now administrators must learn an additional command) by doing this. I wonder if the net result is beneficial or detrimental...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before discussing whether two distinct commands are *needed*:

- `Get-Item` is designed to return information about the targeted item(s) *themselves*.
- `Get-ChildItem` is designed to return information about the targeted item's *children*, *if* a given item happens to be a *container* - which in the case of a *file-system* item applies to *directories* (folders).

  - However, items targeted with a [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expressions *are* always reported as *themselves*, even if they are containers (directories).

Undoubtedly, there is *substantial overlap* between those two cmdlets, with `Get-ChildItem` supporting *many more* (partially provider-specific) features than `Get-Item`. Conversely, there are *a few* features exclusive to `Get-Item`.

---

True: There is *no* strict need for *both* [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) and [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem).

Other shells and platforms make do with just *one* command, which is the equivalent of `Get-ChildItem`, however, not of `Get-Item`:

- `cmd.exe` only comes with its internal `dir` command.
- Unix-like platforms come only with the external `ls` utility.

  - Note: Arguably, it is the external `stat` utility that is the analog of `Get-Item`, but its syntax and output format differ substantially from `ls`. That said, a differing output format needn't be a concern in PowerShell, given that it has a  clear separation between *data* and *its representation*, with the various `Format-*` cmdlets allowing customization of the representations on demand.

For `Get-ChildItem` to fully replace `Get-Item`, it would need to support the following additional features:

- On Windows, the `-Stream` parameter, which only `Get-Item` currently supports.
- Hypothetically, the `-Credential` parameter (according to the linked docs, it is currently not supported by any of the [providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) that ship with PowerShell).
- A (somewhat self-contradictory) way to indicate that you want a literal target path that refers to a *directory* (container) to return information about the directory (container) *itself* rather than its *children*.

  - On Unix-like platforms, the `ls` utility's `-d` option does that - albeit without performing name resolution, such as resolving `.` to the directory's name.
  - By contrast, `cmd.exe`'s `dir` command does *not* directly support that (in other words: it doesn't directly support `Get-Item`'s functionality for *directories*).

Comment: Great answer, as usual, Michael. Contextual information relating to the elements contained in the question, but critically, a direct response to the crux of the question: "There is no strict need for both [cmdlets]."

Comment: In the interests of increasing the simplicity in my code, I will attempt to use only `Get-Item`. It will be interesting to see how far I can get before having to resort to using `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: @Bren0man, well, as  Abraham Zinala has already pointed out, you may run into the need to use `Get-ChildItem`'s  `-Recurse` switch (and, in PowerShell (Core) 7+, `-FollowSymlink`). There's also `-File`, `-Directory` for item-type filtering, and `-Attributes` / `-Hidden` / `-ReadOnly` / `-System` for attribute filtering. Clearly, the bulk of the functionality is attached to `Get-ChildItem`, not `Get-Item`.

Comment: Ahh yes, of course. Turns out not very far then...haha